# android update sdk command reinstalls everything

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager, android-update-sdk

When i run a command like

```
echo 'y'| android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform
```

.. it (re)downloads the latest platforms. If i run it again, it repeats the whole thing again regardless of the fact the sdk is already present.

**Is there a way to 'update' only when something is not already installed/downloaded.**

(`echo 'y'` is to automatically accept licence agreement requests)